# Coupling Android App with Web Service

Tags: android, web-services

I am creating a Webapplication - Food Review site for which we are also developing an android application.

I want to know how to couple the application session of a particular user over the Internet with the application.

When the user logs in thru the application how can i serve them content related to the user alone. How can i know which user is requesting.

I am from a PHP background so i am a little confused how its done in the mobile application

Comment: Mhm just thinking about this.. i don't think you can really have a session for that. I think you have to do a handshake with your application (maybe through AndroidHttpClient) and generate a sessionId which your server (or your application) understands and serves the right content for your user. Just my thoughts.. no reliable answer therefor posted as comment :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can maintain state in the same way a web application does. When a browser stores a cookie all that means is that requests sent to a matching domain get the cookie in the HTTP header. When you construct your HTTP request in Android you have complete control of the headers so it's easy to add your cookie value.

E.G. Post to your authenticator, sending client details. The authenticator would normally respond including the cookie in its response headers, here's a sanitised version of google's cookie setting response headers:

```
Cache-Control:private, max-age=0
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length:173
Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date:Fri, 04 Mar 2011 12:24:32 GMT
Expires:Fri, 04 Mar 2011 12:24:32 GMT
Location:http://www.google.co.uk/
Server:GSE
Set-Cookie:SID=UNIQUESIDGOESHERE;Domain=.google.co.uk;Path=/;Expires=Mon, 01-Mar-2021 12:24:32 GMT
HSID=SOMETHINGELSEUNIQUEHERE;Domain=.google.co.uk;Path=/;Expires=Mon, 01-Mar-2021 12:24:32 GMT;HttpOnly
```

You can read that value and attach it to any http requests you make and the server would be non the wiser that you aren't a normal web browser.

Answer (score 1):

Android is pretty much stateless. (I mean even if it can use states, I haven't come across any such example so far)

So I don't think you can have a session as you have on the web.

You can have a token method to authenticate users for a particular time period. like the OAuth implemented web services do.

Your android app sends the token for each request and your server manages the generation and life of that token along with the permissions.

How does this sound?

Comment: yeah was thinking of the same. but wasnt sure how to build a system like that. can u point me to a guide which explains how i can implement something like this.

Comment: I can only devise a system like this in my mind, but as of now, don't have any link to point you to. on the other note, @CMF has posted a very nice answer. you can also try that method out.